# Filling a polygon with lattice points

Tags: dotfill, lattice

Is there a good way of filling just the interior of the polygon with lattice points without using a /forloop. Maybe something like the /fill function?

Comment: Please add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment. An image of the desired result would also be helpful...

Answer (score 5):

Use a `pattern`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {patterns.meta, shapes.geometric} 

\tikzset{polygrid/.style={draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=#1, pattern={Dots[distance=5mm]}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[polygrid=7, minimum size=5cm]{};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe OP means this `\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {patterns.meta} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[pattern={Dots[distance=3mm]},pattern color=magenta]
(0,0)--(6,0)--(5,4)--(1,3)--cycle
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: @BlackMild: You may be right. It's hard to tell without more information from OP.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an user-defined pattern with TikZ or Asymptote.

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
unitsize(1cm);
import patterns;

picture pic;
real d= 1mm;
fill(pic,box((-d,-d),(d,d)),white);
fill(pic,circle((0,0),d/4));
add("mydots",pic);

path p = (0,0)--(6,-1)--(5,4)--(1,3)--cycle;
filldraw(p,pattern("mydots"),blue);

shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```